# Obtengo error en llamado AJAX

Tags: ajax

Tengo un formulario de factura donde si el cliente entrega parte del pago registro lo que entrego en el efectivo de la caja, y la diferencia con el total va a la cuenta corriente.

Entonces comparo si el vuelto es positivo, osea distinto de cero o menor registro, pero obtengo este error:

> ```
> jquery-3.3.1.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
> at add (jquery-3.3.1.js:8463)
> at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8450)
> at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8444)
> at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-3.3.1.js:8483)
> at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.js:9073)
> at guardarDetalle (indexventa.js:802)
> at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (indexventa.js:178)
> at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
> at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
> ```

Aquí el codigo:

```
function guardarDetalle(){
 var d = new Date();
 var fecha =   d.getMonth() + '-'+ d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();
 var hora = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();  
 var vuelto=$("#Vuelto").val();
 if (vuelto>0){
   var efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "/views/modules/cliente/procesodeuda.php",
        data: 
 {"accion":"acreditar","id":id,"acta":efectivo,"idsesion":sesion}, 


        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },

        });
    }
```

Y es la unica llamada que da ese error, y no estoy enviando un formdata sino valores sueltos digamos. La verdad no entiendo porque

Comment: Si copiaste la función `guardarDetalle` completa te falta un `}` al final

Comment: No. La intencion era copiar el pedido ajax solamente. Ese corchete esta en mi aplicacion. Pero es la primera y unica vez que me ocurre esto